# Growth assumptions on nonlinear term in PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system, lipschitz-functions, boundary-value-problem

In *Partial Differential Equations* book by *Evans* they treat a nonlinear system of reaction-diffusion equations. The nonlinearity comes from the reaction term $f$

\begin{align*}
& \partial_t u - \Delta u = f(u) \ \ \ \ \text{ in } U
& u =0, \ \ \text{ on } \partial U \times [0,T], \ \ \ \ u=g \ \ \text{ on } U \times \{0\}
\end{align*}

It is assumed that the reaction term $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is Lipschitz so it satisfies the growth assumption
$$|f(z)| \leq C(1 + |z|)$$
My question is what is the physical interpretation of the growth assumption?

I am assuming that it puts a restriction on the values of $f$ so it does not grow too fast, or it does not pass a certain value maybe. However, how is this different from assuming that $f$ is bounded?

Are there any other growth assumptions used in the study of PDEs?

**EDIT:**

In this [paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/1996/289648/) for example they assume that $F$ is continuous and $sF(s) \geq 0$. I do not think this has something to do with the growth of $F$, however.

Comment: Physically, a growth assumption often equals the statement that we don't have an infinite source of energy (i.e. if $f$ grows fast with $u$ then the hotter/denser it is then even more heat/particles are added which can lead to an uncontrolled, unphysical, feedback loop). Mathematically, a growth assumption is often only related to what we *need* to assume to be able to prove what we want, or make it easier to prove something or just to be able to prevent a blow-up. My guess its purely mathematical. To figure it out, I would try to study how this condition is actually *used* in the book.